# Can't manage to create a static page with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to make a website using the Zend Framework 2, but I have a simple problem driving me crazy.

I'd like to make a simple about-us.html page with static content because there is no need to do anything else than display html.

There is no need to create a Controller / model etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally, other users will be more inclined to help you, if you show what you have already tried on your own to solve the problem (for example, by showing some code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have to question why you're using ZF in the first place. If you just want to create a static internet page, do that without a PHP framework!

If you didn't ask your question well and you're actually just adding a static page to an existing ZF application, why not just using the existing `IndexController`, add an empty action and add your static content to the corresponding `.phtml`?

Alternatively you can look at [PhlySimplePage](https://github.com/weierophinney/PhlySimplePage), a ZF2 module for the purpose of adding simple static pages to a ZF app. It's written by Matthew Weier O'Phinney, the lead dev of ZF.

As the readme says, this module eliminates the need to create a controller and an action. So all you need to do is create a route and a view script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create controller and view file.
suppose there is a about us menu with link

```
<a href="<?php $this->url('aboutus'array('action'=>'aboutus'));?>">
    About Us
</a>
```

Just go to aboutus view file and write static html code.

Thanks
Alok

Answer (score 0):

I know this question might be old, but I was in trouble with that as well.

Here is what I did to create a generic router for my application, so I could just add as many actions as I need and have then created as phtml files in my view

on module.config.php

```
'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:action][/]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

So basically what it does is gets any action you might have in your application and use as a page... like any other controller

Instead of http://yoursite.com/application/test
you can do now http://yoursite.com/test

if you have your testAction set in your indexController file.

Hope I had helped future people looking for this information.